# parsing txt from array to UILabel

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, uilabel

I'm actually starting to loose the will to live, this piece of code is driving me nuts!

I'm trying to get the content of mathspractice.txt into *myLabel

I'm using an array which is:

```
-(void)loadText
{
    NSArray *wordListArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
    [[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”mathspractice” ofType:@”txt”]
    encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding error:NULL] componentsSeparatedByString:@”\n”]];
    self.theMathsPractice = wordListArray;
    [wordListArray release];
}
```

and then I'm trying to pass it into *myLabel

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,960,40)];
        myLabel.text = *theMathsPractice;
        [myScrollView addSubview:myLabel];
        [myLabel release];
        }
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks on quick inspection that your `theMathsPractice` is an NSArray, not an NSString, which is what you'd want to assign to the label's text property. You should at least format that array back into a string of some sort before assigning it to the label.

(Also not sure why you're dereferencing it with the `*` in the assignment-- I would think that would throw a compiler error, since naked non-reference Objective-C objects are not really allowed.)

Comment: Thanks Ben, I understand what I was missing now... I'll post back! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following:

```
myLable.text = [theMathsPractice componentsJoinedByString:@" "]);
```