# From NSArray to UILabel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

My code compiles fine but doesn't show the text from mathspractice.txt

```
-(void)loadText
{
 NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
 NSString *textFilePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"mathspractice" ofType:@"txt"];
 NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath];
 NSArray *mathsPracticeTextArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
 self.mathsPracticeText = mathsPracticeTextArray;
 [mathsPracticeTextArray release];
}
```

and:

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,960,40)];
 myLabel.text = [mathsPracticeText componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
 [myScrollView addSubview:myLabel];
 [myLabel release];
```

can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the text is being loaded correctly into mathsPracticText?

Comment: What's mathsPractiveText?  Also I don't see a purpose of splitting the file if you're just joining them again later

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327656/parsing-txt-from-array-to-uilabel

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies with the line

```
self.mathsPracticeText = mathsPracticeTextArray;
```

If I understand correctly mathsPracticeText is a string.  Then with this line:

```
myLabel.text = [mathsPracticeText componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

nothing will happen because you tried to load the entire array into a string, instead you should do something more like this:

```
-(void)loadText
{
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *textFilePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"mathspractice" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath];
mathsPracticeText = fileContents;
[mathsPracticeTextArray release];
}
```

and

```
 UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,100,960,40)];
 [myLabel setText:mathsPracticeText];
 [myScrollView addSubview:myLabel];
 [myLabel release];
```

Answer (score 1):

In Cocoa Touch, there’s no `+[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:]` (and on the desktop it’s deprecated). You have to use `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:`.

There’s no obvious other error in your code, but that doesn’t mean that everything is right. You didn’t post the declaration of `mathsPracticeText`, for instance, but I assume it’s an `NSArray`.

You’re fiddling a little too much with the arrays in the construction. Instead of building a second array from `[fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]` which you later release, you could simply use the one returned from `componentsSeparatedByString:`

```
-(void)loadText
{
    NSString *textFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mathspractice" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:textFilePath
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                          error:NULL];
    self.mathsPracticeText = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
}
```